# Android Facebook Sdk 4.11.0 How to post a simple status update to wall without any link or image

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to build an app that updates a user's facebook status when the user gives a voice input like "update my status to enjoying holidays at Newyork " and "enjoying holidays at Newyork" will be posted as user's status.

How can i do this ?

I have tried shareLinkContet but it seems to share a link with some description and also tried setting setContentTitle and setContentUrl to null but failed,I have been using Facebook Android Sdk 4.11.0 ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have finally got the answer

```
  GraphRequest request=GraphRequest.newPostRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "me/feed", null, new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                     Log.d(TAG,"STATUS UPDATED SUCESSFULLY");
        }
    });
    Bundle parameters=new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("message","hellow everyone from newyork");
     request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
```

this works perfectly